Can you receive a PhD offer in late April?
I had applied for PhD to a university, I was asked to sit for an interview in late January with my prospective supervisors who told me that they like me. 15th April has passed and I have had no response from the University, the professor who had been helping me out with my application, and has otherwise been prompt with responses has gone silent when I asked him the status of my application after the 15th of April and so has the graduate advisor for this course. It's 20th April now.
What could be the reason for them ghosting me out? Why am I being ignored by both the professor and the graduate coordinator? Should I consider myself rejected at this point?

Please see the linked canonical question. The relevant paragraph states: “ For US graduate admissions, most decisions are made between mid-January and mid-April. If you haven't heard anything by mid-March, it's probably not good news, but some students do get admitted later, even after the April 15 deadline.”

Rolled this back because you re-posted the same question separately.

Now, one question is what happened to the communication since one would have expected some answer. Did you hear anything after the interview? I presume US, but confirming in the text would help.

A month after the interview, I asked the professor about the status, he said I'm still under consideration. This was 19th March. And then I asked about my status on the 14th, no response since.

I do not know your field, but most PhD offers go out well before April, with a deadline to respond around April 15.
Given the lack of response from your prospective advisor and program, it is likely you will not receive an offer.
